# Wrong Output with the following code

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener

I tried to implement a simple GUI application,having a class extend JPanel and then adding it to a frame and adding a button,but nothing happens when I click on the button.What is wrong?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class dup extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.green);

        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, this.WIDTH, this.HEIGHT);
        System.out.println("inside paint component class");
    }
}

public class drawing implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame;
    dup d1;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        drawing d2 = new drawing();
        d2.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        JButton button = new JButton("click me");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        d1 = new dup();
        button.addActionListener(this);

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, d1);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        frame.repaint();

    }
}
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: Do you see the debug message "inside paint component"?

Comment: Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.  But +1 for posting an SSCCE. :)

Comment: Moreover in your `actionPerformed()` method, if you might will try to modify the values for `dup (JPanel)` for it to be reciprocated on it, then I guess you need to use `d1.repaint()` and not `frame.repaint()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Width and height is wrong. It should be

```
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
```

You were using constants from `ImageObserver` class instead of width and height properties of the component.